# Why is line width in CoreGraphics on retina display rendered half width?

Tags: core-graphics, retina-display, cgcontext

My process looks like this:

- define a rectangle I want to draw in, using point dimensions.
- define `CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainsScreen] scale]`
- Multiply the rectangle's size by the scale
- Create an image context of the rectangle size using `CGBitmapContextCreate`
- Draw within the image context
- call `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`
- call `UIImage imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation`: with the appropriate scale.

I had thought this has always resulted in perfect images on both retina and and older screens, but haven't been paying close attention to the line contrast/thickness. Generally, the strokes have a high contrast to the fill so I didn't paid attention until now, with low contrast between a line and fill.

I think perhaps I'm misunderstanding the user space, but I thought it was simply a direct conversion through the scaling, and transforms applied. There are no scaling and transforms applied in my particular case except for the retina screen double scaling.

Trying to render a 2-pixel line rather than 1-pixel is easier to explain: when I call
`UIContextSetLineWidth(context, 2)`, the line is rendered as 1 pixel thick on the retina simulator.  1 pixel!  But this should be two pixels, on a retina display.

`UIContextSetLineWidth(context, 2 * scale)` produces a line that is two pixels wide on a retina screen, but I'm expecting it to be 4 pixels.

`UIContextSetLineWidth(context, 1)` produces a 1-pixel wide line that is partly transparent.  I understand about the stroke straddling the path, so I prefer talking in terms of 2-pixel-wide strokes and the paths being on pixel boundaries.

I need to understand why the rendered line width is being divided in half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault.  99% of my own bugs I solve on my own just after I post publicly about it.

The drawing code includes **CGContextClip** after constructing and copying a path.  After that, a fill may be applied, gradient or otherwise, then the line drawn, so everything is nice and tidy.  I was focusing on the math and specific drawing code, and did not notice the clipping line, but that would effectively **halve the stroke width**.  Normally I catch logic bugs like this immediately, but because it was posted to SO, it's appropriate the answer is here too.